# Different inputs for the same function

Tags: c++

So I have a function that takes in 2 different inputs.

I've ran into the situation, however, where I very occasionally need a third input. Most of the time I don't though.

The solution I currently have is that the actual function I want to use is only called by 2 other functions. These two functions have the same name, but 1 takes 3 input and the other 2 (with this one just setting a null value to the third input before calling the original function).

This works quite well, but it feels like there might be a much better way of handling this type of problem. The only other solution I have is to declare a null value of the third input every time I go to call the first function, but that seems even messier.

Is there a better way to do this? Is it bad form the way I've written it?

Comment: Could you illustrate the problem with some code? The answer would depend on the details.

Comment: An overload, such as you desribe, doesn't seem THAT bad:)

Comment: Yeah, I guess not. The Default arguments solution that Luchian posted seems a fair bit neater though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default arguments:

```
void foo (int x, int y, int z = 0);
```

Unless you pass a third value, `z` will be `0` by default inside the function.

Comment: Ah, that's neat, thanks! Quick follow up though, the value is an enum and I've normally just been declaring it with "LeaderLineEnum defaultLeader;". Do you know how I'd go about replicating that as a default argument?

Comment: The google coding style guide has some strong arguments against default arguments (http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Default_Arguments).

Comment: @Incredidave just put `= defaultValue`.

Comment: @arne it's also against passing by reference IIRC.

Comment: Hmm, it says defaultValue is undefined.

Comment: @Incredidave did you include the header where the enum is declared before declaring the function?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Not quite. It specifies that reference arguments need to be `const`. If you want to modify, you should use pointers instead.

Comment: yeah, I have the header included (I mean it recognises the actual enum type itself, which I guess it wouldn't if it wasn't being included)

Comment: I'm surprised it isn't just letting me set it to an int either. The enum assigned to 0 would have been fine.

Comment: @Incredidave `defaultValue` was meant to be replaced with the actual default value, I am pretty sure. IIRC you can just use the typename with `()` and it gives the default constructed value.

Comment: ¬_¬ Yeah, I just got it working. The actual problem I was having was that I was using the name of the default type but forgetting the namespace in front of it despite using it like 2 words earlier. So yeah, thats that solved. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Aaaannnd I had to go back to my original solution because you can't do default values with managed code. Well, I learned something at least.

Comment: @arne You won't be taken seriously if you back up a claim about C++ with Google Style Guide. It is almost as bad as the FQA.

Comment: @Cubbi I don't like this style guide as a whole, I just think it has some good arguments for some of the rules. Most of the rules are rather ridicuous, that's true.